# Turning a .bin file into a .txt file of readable data

Tags: python, binary, post-processing

I am working on a project which requires me to use a .bin file containing information and plot the evolution of these informations in function of the time.

The file contains text informations. They start by a # so I can easily remove them. Then, the file consists in data arranged in lines. Here is what each line of the file contains :

```
#
# Columns description
# Column 01 : Line count
# Column 02 : Time [s]
# Column 03 : Frame count
# Column 04 : PLL 1 / Channel 1  -  Frequency [Hz] 
# Column 05 : PLL 1 / Channel 1 - In-phase amplitude [V] 
# Column 06 : PLL 1 / Channel 1 - In-quad amplitude [V] 
# Column 07 : PLL 1 / Channel 1 - Phase difference [rad] 
# Column 08 : PLL 1 / Channel 2  -  Frequency [Hz] 
# Column 09 : PLL 1 / Channel 2 - In-phase amplitude [V] 
# Column 10 : PLL 1 / Channel 2 - In-quad amplitude [V] 
# Column 11 : PLL 1 / Channel 2 - Phase difference [rad] 
# Column 12 : PLL 1 / Channel 3  -  Frequency [Hz] 
# Column 13 : PLL 1 / Channel 3 - In-phase amplitude [V] 
# Column 14 : PLL 1 / Channel 3 - In-quad amplitude [V] 
# Column 15 : PLL 1 / Channel 3 - Phase difference [rad] 
# Column 16 : PLL 1 / Channel 4  -  Frequency [Hz] 
# Column 17 : PLL 1 / Channel 4 - In-phase amplitude [V] 
# Column 18 : PLL 1 / Channel 4 - In-quad amplitude [V] 
# Column 19 : PLL 1 / Channel 4 - Phase difference [rad] 
# Column 20 : PLL 1 / Channel 5  -  Frequency [Hz] 
# Column 21 : PLL 1 / Channel 5 - In-phase amplitude [V] 
# Column 22 : PLL 1 / Channel 5 - In-quad amplitude [V] 
# Column 23 : PLL 1 / Channel 5 - Phase difference [rad] 
# Column 24 : PLL 1 / Channel 6  -  Frequency [Hz] 
# Column 25 : PLL 1 / Channel 6 - In-phase amplitude [V] 
# Column 26 : PLL 1 / Channel 6 - In-quad amplitude [V] 
# Column 27 : PLL 1 / Channel 6 - Phase difference [rad] 
# Column 28 : PLL 1 / Channel 7  -  Frequency [Hz] 
# Column 29 : PLL 1 / Channel 7 - In-phase amplitude [V] 
# Column 30 : PLL 1 / Channel 7 - In-quad amplitude [V] 
# Column 31 : PLL 1 / Channel 7 - Phase difference [rad] 
# Column 32 : PLL 1 / Channel 8  -  Frequency [Hz] 
# Column 33 : PLL 1 / Channel 8 - In-phase amplitude [V] 
# Column 34 : PLL 1 / Channel 8 - In-quad amplitude [V] 
# Column 35 : PLL 1 / Channel 8 - Phase difference [rad] 
# Column 36 : PLL 2 / Channel 1  -  Frequency [Hz] 
# Column 37 : PLL 2 / Channel 1 - In-phase amplitude [V] 
# Column 38 : PLL 2 / Channel 1 - In-quad amplitude [V] 
# Column 39 : PLL 2 / Channel 1 - Phase difference [rad] 
# Column 40 : PLL 2 / Channel 2  -  Frequency [Hz] 
# Column 41 : PLL 2 / Channel 2 - In-phase amplitude [V] 
# Column 42 : PLL 2 / Channel 2 - In-quad amplitude [V] 
# Column 43 : PLL 2 / Channel 2 - Phase difference [rad] 
# Column 44 : PLL 2 / Channel 3  -  Frequency [Hz] 
# Column 45 : PLL 2 / Channel 3 - In-phase amplitude [V] 
# Column 46 : PLL 2 / Channel 3 - In-quad amplitude [V] 
# Column 47 : PLL 2 / Channel 3 - Phase difference [rad] 
# Column 48 : PLL 2 / Channel 4  -  Frequency [Hz] 
# Column 49 : PLL 2 / Channel 4 - In-phase amplitude [V] 
# Column 50 : PLL 2 / Channel 4 - In-quad amplitude [V] 
# Column 51 : PLL 2 / Channel 4 - Phase difference [rad] 
# Column 52 : PLL 2 / Channel 5  -  Frequency [Hz] 
# Column 53 : PLL 2 / Channel 5 - In-phase amplitude [V] 
# Column 54 : PLL 2 / Channel 5 - In-quad amplitude [V] 
# Column 55 : PLL 2 / Channel 5 - Phase difference [rad] 
# Column 56 : PLL 2 / Channel 6  -  Frequency [Hz] 
# Column 57 : PLL 2 / Channel 6 - In-phase amplitude [V] 
# Column 58 : PLL 2 / Channel 6 - In-quad amplitude [V] 
# Column 59 : PLL 2 / Channel 6 - Phase difference [rad] 
# Column 60 : PLL 2 / Channel 7  -  Frequency [Hz] 
# Column 61 : PLL 2 / Channel 7 - In-phase amplitude [V] 
# Column 62 : PLL 2 / Channel 7 - In-quad amplitude [V] 
# Column 63 : PLL 2 / Channel 7 - Phase difference [rad] 
# Column 64 : PLL 2 / Channel 8  -  Frequency [Hz] 
# Column 65 : PLL 2 / Channel 8 - In-phase amplitude [V] 
# Column 66 : PLL 2 / Channel 8 - In-quad amplitude [V] 
# Column 67 : PLL 2 / Channel 8 - Phase difference [rad] 
#
```

The number of lines in each file depends on the duration of the acquisition. The data on each line is written in **binary**. I am trying to read the file line by line, skip the line if it starts with # as it contains information (see above) and them extract the data from each line, value by value (column by column) and finally convert it to decimal values. The data can be positive or negative.

Here is my code for now :

```
import unicodedata
import struct
import os
import numpy as np

if os.path.exists("out.txt"):
    os.remove("out.txt")
else :
    print("The file does not exist")

my_data = "TestData.bin"
rb = "rb"
out = open("out.txt", "w")
with open(my_data, "rb") as file :
    line = file.readline()
    while line[0] == "#" :
        line = file.readline()
        buffer = struct.unpack('dddd', line[0:32])
        out.write(str(buffer))
    while line :
        line = file.readline()
        if len(line) >= 32 :
            buffer = struct.unpack('dddd', line[0:32])
            out.write(str(buffer))
        else :
            pass
out.close()
```

In the out.txt file, I get values but they are incorrect. I think I am using the library struct in the wrong way but I can not seem to make it work properly. Does someone has an idea on what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: `readline` gets chunks that end with `\n` = `0x0A`. This can't work with binary data that might contain such bytes.

Comment: Understood. So I need to remove the information (#) part beforehand and then use a different method for the binary data ?

Comment: That's probably one of the easiest ways, yes. For the binary data, if you know how many bytes a row contains, just `read()` that many bytes in you loop.

Comment: Ok I will try to get the size of the lines. Is there anyway I can get the size in bytes of each line ? (Just as an help to know how many bytes my line contains)